# Get position X,Y from list from html

Tags: angular, typescript, arraylist, scroll

I have input text that user can search element and I have list, I would like to scroll to the element from this list when user put it but I can't get the position X,Y for the specific element in the list, this my code

```
<input type="text" (change)="search(event)">
<div *ngFor="let item from list">
{{item.lib}}
</div>
```

```
search(event:any){
let itemSearch = event.target.value;
this.list = this.list.filter((val)=>{
if(val.lib.indexOf(itemSearch)>=0){
let scrollY= val.lib.indexOf(itemSearch);
if(scrollY !==-1){
document.querySelector('.scroll')?.scroll (0,Scroll);
}
}
)};
This.list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren). If you use a template reference variable

```
<div #divItem *ngFor="let item from list">
{{item.lib}}
</div>

@ViewChildren('divItem') listDiv:QueryList<ElementRef>
```

In your function search

```
//first We lookfor the index of the Array
const index=this.list.findIndex(x=>indexOf(word)>=0)
if (index>=0)
{
   //we find in the QueryList the element that has the "index"
   const el=this.listDiv.find((_,i)=>i==index)
   console.log(el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect())
   //you can use also
   el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView()
}
```

NOTE: You can use also a template reference variable in your input in the way

```
<input #input type="text" (input)="search(input.value)">

search(word:string){
   ....
}
```

Comment: It didn't work with @viewChildren I have error that is undefined I try to search to find solution

Comment: I do it with @ViewChildren but it is not good for position, I scroll for this position for getBoundingClientRec() but is not good.

Comment: It works thank you

Comment: @Ines, be carafull, I has used the same name for the array and for the QueryList. It's wrong, I just corrected named as listDivs and list

Comment: Yes I see that thank you.